# How to fix issue with Azure Web App Services return Error 503

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have deployed in Azure Portal some app services under a free plan. The apps seem to be healthy and were working without problems until today. Suddenly all of them are returning an `Error 503 "The service is unavailable."`.

Under one of the services in `Diagnose and fix problems` in azure portal I checked CPU, Memory, Port usage and everything looks healthy.

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?
Could that be Microsoft maintenance and after some hours the sites are working normally again?

Comment: Try to upgrade your price tier as there are limits on the free plan such as a limit of 10 apps per free plan. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/

Comment: @NancyXiong the services after 5 hours were up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 5 hours the services were up again. Probably it was a maintenance issue. So after no indication that my services have a problem, waiting some hours was the solution. Maybe this [site](http://https:/https://status.azure.com/en-us/status/) that displays the azure status could be helpful for those that run into this problem.